# How to derive the equivalence of this two equation

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-analysis

Knowing the properties of fourier transform on differention,
$$j\omega \mathcal{F}(\omega)=\int f'(t)e^{-jwt}dt$$

Are these two terms equal?
$$ -j\omega \int x(p)e^{-jw(N-p)}dp = \int x'(p)e^{-jw(N-p)}dp$$

If not, what am I missing?

Comment: The sign might be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will start with the regular, time shifted, fourier transform pair:
$$x(t-t_0) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int e^{-j\omega t_0} X(\omega) e^{j\omega t} \mathrm d \omega$$
We perform time reversal
\begin{equation}
x(-t-t_0) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int e^{j\omega t_0}X(-\omega) e^{j\omega t} \mathrm d \omega
\end{equation}

And differentiation with respect to time (note the minus sign due to the chain rule):
$$-x'(-t-t_0) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int e^{j\omega t_0}j\omega X(-\omega) e^{j\omega t} \mathrm d \omega$$

We get the pair:
$$e^{j\omega t_0} j\omega X(-\omega) = -\int_{-\infty}^\infty x'(-t-t_0) e^{-j\omega t} \mathrm d t$$

We write the left side as $j \omega$ times the fourier transform of $x(-t-t_0)$, see above for the validity.
$$j\omega \int_{-\infty}^\infty x(-t-t_0) e^{-j\omega t} \mathrm d t = -\int_{-\infty}^\infty x'(-t-t_0) e^{-j\omega t} \mathrm d t$$

We now set $N=-t_0$ and perform a substitution of variables with $t=N-p$ and thus $\mathrm d t = -\mathrm d p$, note we do not have to change the limits of the integral because we do this on both sides and the minus signs cancel, the other minus signs from the substitution also cancel and we end up with:
$$j\omega \int_{-\infty}^\infty x(-(-t_0-p)-t_0) e^{-j\omega (N-p)} \mathrm d p = -\int_{-\infty}^\infty x'(-(-t_0-p)-t_0) e^{-j\omega (N-p)} \mathrm d p$$
Gives
$$-j\omega \int_{-\infty}^\infty x(p) e^{-j\omega (N-p)} \mathrm d p = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x'(p) e^{-j\omega (N-p)} \mathrm d p$$

Thus the formula you have given is correct.

Comment: Great! Thanks @joris.